# Is it possible to run a R script using a web server?

Tags: r, webserver

Is it possible to run a R script using a web server, similar to Perl CGI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and you can even run [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) remotely on a webpage.
If you want to just run a R script, you have several options:

- you can simply ssh your computer that have R
- find an [online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php) solution (here is the [list](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces) from CRAN).
- build your own server with [Rook](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rook/index.html)
- depending what you want to do a [shiny app](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) could help as well
- You have other solutions such as [rApache](http://rapache.net/) if you didn't like other soltutions